# (corebluetooth didUpdateValueFor) data is not being sent properly between my peripheral arduino 33 nano and iOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

can someone please help me understand why my iOS app is not recognizing data that is being sent over from an arduino device? i have pasted debug prints throughout and im finding that my code isnt even entering the functions that deal with data retrieval. i can send my code over as you require. thank you so much.

arduino: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GpkA0fxoyWs7-ckFk8yIK_EnQWxRX4D2/view?usp=drive_link

xcode (bluetoothserial and pastmeasurements controller): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l5l7dJ5yxLFNsNJKYO1rGk0AhsXgKw9X?usp=sharing

in the controller (pastmeasurements controller) that deals with the page that logs the transmission of info from arduino to xcode, i use the function serialDidReceiveString() but again, since there is some issue with updating the characteristics it doesnt work and thus doesnt call the didUpdateCharacteristic function within the bluetooth serial file.